# Does the Acer V3-772G have mSATA?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, upgrade

[Here on the manufacturer product page for the V3-772G-9829](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model-datasheet/NX.M74AA.002) is listed "dual hard drive support".

Is that an mSATA slot, second SATA (1.8" or 2.5"), or does installing a second hard drive require replacing the optical drive and using its bay?

Comment: In the images for that laptop over at [Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834314149), the second to last one that shows the bottom of the laptop and from that it appears to me that _dual hard drive support_ means that the laptop has two 2.5" SATA bays.

Answer (score 1):

I am waiting for my V3-772G to come in today in the evening, and I specifically bought it because it has an mSATA slot, you can see it in the [video review](http://youtu.be/eK9L-n0Urno?t=3m48s). Although it is probably a different model than you are asking about, I believe they all have the same chassis and the same extension slot configuration.

Edit: I have received the laptop, and I can confirm that my model has two hard drive slots and one additional mSATA slot. My model is `V3-772G-747a8G1TMakk`.